# Align center until there isn't enough space WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, layout

I have a particular layout behavior in mind, and I want to see if anyone can come up with a simple way of doing this before I try to write a custom panel or something. Take a look at this animation I manually put together:

[image: Shrinking example animation]

There is an element of fixed width to the far left (the rectangle), and then a second element that is centered- not within the remaining space, but relative to the entire container. As the container shrinks, the centered element stays centered *until* the left element gets too close. Instead of staying directly in the middle, the "centered" element now stays as close to the center as possible *without* overlapping. This is the behavior I want.

Using a `Grid`, I can do something like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Border Width="100" Background="Green"/>

    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" FontSize="24" Margin="2, 0">Centered Text</TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Which puts everything in the right place, but the `TextBlock` will start overlapping with the `Border` instead of moving further right.

So any idea how I can get this to do what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try:

Name of  Window `x:Name="window1"`

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Border x:Name="border1" Width="100" Background="Green"/>

    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"  FontSize="24"    Grid.ColumnSpan="2">Centered Text</TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

SizeChanged event

```
     private void Window1_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e) {
        if(( ( window1.Width / 2 ) - ( textBlock1.ActualWidth / 2 ) - border1.Width - ( SystemParameters.ResizeFrameVerticalBorderWidth * 2 ) ) <= 0) {
            Grid.SetColumn(textBlock1, 1);
            textBlock1.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;

        } else {
            Grid.SetColumn(textBlock1, 0);
            textBlock1.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well, that's definitly simpler than making a custom panel, thanks. I made a few changes: I used the `Grid.ActualWidth` instead of `Window.Width` and left out `SystemParameters.ResizeFrameVerticalBorderWidth`. I also added in the right margin of the left element and the left margin of the centered element.